# Querying by parent and child key

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have this structure in a document:

```
{
    "_id": "a04ecdc29276760e689dd8148d000e7c",
    "type": "user",
    "user": "xxx",
    "categories": [
        {
            "type": "TYPE1",
            "id": "3523683f7930be3a2e5c8496c800083a"
        },
        {
            "type": "TYPE2",
            "id": "bd2098d428d36ffd895f37b872000951"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I want (preferrably) in one query fetch the user and his/hers associated categories, whose ids are references to other documents, hence the include_docs, filtered by user and category type. I managed this:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.type === "user") {
        emit(doc.user, null);
        if (doc.categories) {
            for (var i = 0, child; child = doc.categories[i]; ++i) {
                emit(child.type, {_id: child.id});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can run this with http get:

```
http://localhost:5984/_design/foo/_view/by_user?startkey=["xxx"]&endkey["xxx",{}]&include_docs=true
```

which will give me the user and the associated categories, not taking into account the category type.

How would I go about to query on user AND category type as key parameters? I know I could create a view for each category type and do emit([doc.user, doc.TYPE]) but seeing as the categories are created on the fly, this is probably not an option.

Can this even be done with one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key can be arbitrary JSON as well.  Change your emit to:

`emit([doc.user, child.type], ...)`

Then your starkey would be:

`["xxx", "TYPE1"]`

and endkey:

`["xxx", "TYPE1", {}]`